# Render images from files array on client with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, file, file-upload

I am new to React and I'm implementing a multi-file upload system. I current have implemented user driven file selection via a click event handler on a button which adds the selected file into an array.

For some reason when ever I select a file, the following error is shown in the console which causes the application to stop working:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead

For reference, my interface for this functionality looks like:
[image]

And here are the relevant parts of my component implementation:

```
state = {
  selectedPortifolio: {},
  portflioFiles: []
}
```

And this method is called on the file onchange event

```
loadPortfolio = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files) {
            this.setState({
                selectedPortifolio: {
                    file: e.target.files[0],
                    filename: e.target.files[0].name
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

And when add button is clicked then this method is called.

```
addPortfolio = () => {
        if (
            this.state.selectedPortifolio &&
            this.state.selectedPortifolio.file
        ) {
            let items = this.state.portflioFiles;
            items.push(this.state.selectedPortifolio);
            this.setState({ selectedPortifolio: {}, portflioFiles: items });
            console.log(this.state.portflioFiles);
        }
    };
```

After all this i load this array into the div

```
{this.state.portflioFiles.length > 0 ? (
    this.state.portflioFiles.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="portfolio-file" key={index}>
                {getDataURL(item.file).then((data) => {
                    return (
                        <image
                            src={data}
                            alt={item.filename}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    })
) : (
    <div></fdv>
)}
```

And getDataURL method is defined in another file.

```
export const getDataURL = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your code is attempting to directly render promise objects  by mapping `portfolioItems` via the call to `getDataURL()` function. At the moment, React is based on synchronous rendering which means "promise-based rendering" is not currently possbile with React.

To achieve what you require, consider resolving the promises returned by `getDataURL()` outside of your rendering logic (ie in `addPortfolio()`).

This would require that your component state is extended to hold the image data resolved by the promise returned by `getDataURL()`. You'd then update the rendering logic of your component so that images a rendered from image data now present in your component state:

**Update state shape**

```
state = {
  selectedPortifolio: {},
  portflioFiles: [],
  portflioImages : [] // Extend state with arrage for image data
}
```

---

**Update addPortfolio()**

```
addPortfolio = () => {
        if (
            this.state.selectedPortifolio &&
            this.state.selectedPortifolio.file
        ) {
            let items = this.state.portflioFiles;
            let images = this.state.portflioImages;
            items.push(this.state.selectedPortifolio);

            // Resolve promise outside of render-logic. Once data 
            // required for rendering is available, update state
            // to trigger a re-render
            getDataURL(this.state.selectedPortifolio).then((image) => {
                this.setState({ 
                  selectedPortifolio: {}, 
                  portflioFiles: items,
                  // Add resolved image to portflioImages images array
                  portflioImages : images.concat([image]) 
            });
          });
        }
    };
```

---

**Update render logic**

```
{this.state.portflioImages.length > 0 ? (
    /* map portflioImages directly to image without promise */
    this.state.portflioImages.map((imageSrc, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="portfolio-file" key={index}>
                <img src={imageSrc} alt={item.filename} />
            </div>
        );
    })
) : (
    <div></fdv>
)}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So i convert the file to dataurl at the time when user click on add button ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, you want to shift the promise/async code into the click event handler and then update your component state with the data needed to support rendering so that rendering does not require async/promise based function calls

Comment: Src is coming in the image but image is broken

Comment: My apologies - there was an small error in my answer. Please see the use of `imageSrc` in the updated render logic. Does that help?